# python set does not remove duplicates... Why?

Tags: python, duplicates, set

I create manually a set to remove duplicates:

```
mi_primer_set = {
'Pearson Educación',
'Innova Ediciones ',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Larousse',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ángeles Editores ',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Larousse',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Innova Ediciones ',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ek Editores',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Larousse',
'Fernández Educación ',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Fernández Editores',
'Patria Educación',
'Larousse',
'Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones SM',
'Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Ediciones SM',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ángeles Editores',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Cervantes',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Fernández Educación',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Siglo XXI Editores',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Oxford University Press',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Pearson Educación',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Fernández Educación',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones Ángeles Hermanos',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Siglo XXI Editores',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Ángeles Editores',
'Pearson Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Oxford University Press',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Pearson Educación',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Edebé',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Trillas',
'University of Dayton Publishing ',
'University of Dayton Publishing ',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Edebé',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'U.D. Publishing ',
'U.D. Publishing ',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Santillana',
'University of Dayton Publishing',
'Macmillan Publishers',
}
```

The set has 41 elements.

I show the 41 elements:

```
len(mi_primer_set)
#result 41


for elemento in mi_primer_set :
 print(elemento)
```

The result:

```
Ángeles Editores
Ángeles Editores
Correo del Maestro
Edebé
Ediciones Ángeles Hermanos
Ediciones Castillo
Ediciones de Excelencia
Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.
Ediciones Larousse
Ediciones SM
Editorial Cervantes
Editorial Esfinge
Editorial Limusa
Editorial Nuevo México
Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives
Editorial Santillana
Editorial Santillana
Editorial Terracota
Editorial Trillas
Ek Editores
EPSA / McGraw-Hill
Fernández Editores
Fernández Educación
Fernández Educación
Grupo Editorial Patria
Innova Ediciones
Innova Ediciones
Larousse
Macmillan Publishers
Méndez Cortés Editores
Norma Ediciones
Oxford University Press
Patria Educación
Pearson Educación
Richmond Publishing
Ríos de Tinta
Santillana
Siglo XXI Editores
U.D. Publishing
University of Dayton Publishing
University of Dayton Publishing
```

You can see "Innova Ediciones" appears twice. Why?

You can see "Ángeles Editores" appears twice. Why?

You can see "University of Dayton Publishing" appears twice. Why?

You can see "Editorial Santillana" appears twice. Why?

With the 41 elements I create a second set:

```
mi_segundo_set = { 
'Ángeles Editores',
'Ángeles Editores',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Edebé',
'Ediciones Ángeles Hermanos',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Cervantes',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ek Editores',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Fernández Editores',
'Fernández Educación',
'Fernández Educación',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Larousse',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Oxford University Press',
'Patria Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Santillana',
'Siglo XXI Editores',
'U.D. Publishing',
'University of Dayton Publishing',
'University of Dayton Publishing',
}
```

The second set has 36 elements and finally removes the three duplicated elements.

```
len(mi_segundo_set)


for elemento in mi_segundo_set:
 print(elemento)

Ángeles Editores
Correo del Maestro
Edebé
Ediciones Ángeles Hermanos
Ediciones Castillo
Ediciones de Excelencia
Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.
Ediciones Larousse
Ediciones SM
Editorial Cervantes
Editorial Esfinge
Editorial Limusa
Editorial Nuevo México
Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives
Editorial Santillana
Editorial Terracota
Editorial Trillas
Ek Editores
EPSA / McGraw-Hill
Fernández Editores
Fernández Educación
Grupo Editorial Patria
Innova Ediciones
Larousse
Macmillan Publishers
Méndez Cortés Editores
Norma Ediciones
Oxford University Press
Patria Educación
Pearson Educación
Richmond Publishing
Ríos de Tinta
Santillana
Siglo XXI Editores
U.D. Publishing
University of Dayton Publishing
```

Why?

How can I avoid this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the spelling/spaces/capitalization the same in the *duplicates*?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in "the result".

Comment: Yes.. its the same.

Comment: I can' spot any duplicates in your first output

Comment: No it isn't, `'Innova Ediciones' != 'Innova Ediciones '`, for example

Comment: there is 4 Innova Ediciones, two of those are 'Innova Ediciones' and the other two are 'Innova Ediciones '. So each of those will remain in the set. Same for the other cases, just trailling white spaces

Comment: It should also be noted that the "result" section was edited after the fact. The original didn't even contain close duplicates.

Comment: Trailing spaces is the cause of apparent but not really duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, you have trailing spaces after some of your entries and therefore the entries appear duplicated when you print them, but in fact, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe Thank you for your support.

An improved version to avoid whitespaces at the beginning and the end:

```
mi_lista = [
'Pearson Educación',
'Innova Ediciones ',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Larousse',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ángeles Editores ',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Larousse',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Innova Ediciones ',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ek Editores',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana ',
'Larousse',
'Fernández Educación ',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Innova Ediciones',
'Fernández Editores',
'Patria Educación',
'Larousse',
'Ediciones Impresas y Digitales Del Río, S.A. de C.V.',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Progreso Grupo Edelvives',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones SM',
'Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ek Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Ediciones SM',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ángeles Editores',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones SM',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Cervantes',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Fernández Educación',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Siglo XXI Editores',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Ediciones SM',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Fernández Educación',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Oxford University Press',
'Oxford University Press',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Pearson Educación',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Fernández Educación',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Ediciones Ángeles Hermanos',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Siglo XXI Editores',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones SM',
'Fernández Educación',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones SM',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Pearson Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Editorial Limusa',
'Ángeles Editores',
'Pearson Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Oxford University Press',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Nuevo México',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Editorial Trillas',
'EPSA / McGraw-Hill',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Méndez Cortés Editores',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones SM',
'Ediciones SM',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Norma Ediciones',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Ediciones de Excelencia',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Esfinge',
'Editorial Terracota',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Grupo Editorial Patria',
'Fernández Educación',
'Editorial Santillana',
'Ediciones SM',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Ediciones Larousse',
'Pearson Educación',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Edebé',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Editorial Trillas',
'Editorial Trillas',
'University of Dayton Publishing ',
'University of Dayton Publishing ',
'Larousse',
'Correo del Maestro',
'Patria Educación',
'Pearson Educación',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Edebé',
'Ríos de Tinta',
'U.D. Publishing ',
'U.D. Publishing ',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Macmillan Publishers',
'Richmond Publishing',
'Ediciones Castillo',
'Santillana',
'University of Dayton Publishing',
'Macmillan Publishers',
]

mi_set = set()

for elemento in mi_lista:
    elemento = elemento.strip()
    mi_set.add(elemento)
```

A further enhacement: remove double space inside element.

Comment: Wow, almost like my answer. This is just what I do.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, your initial set doesn't have duplicates. The string with extra space at the end is different from the string without that space.
You asked how to avoid this.

While creating your initial set, if you are iterating over strings to add to a list, then use the python function `strip()`

For example

```
mystring1='Innova Ediciones '
mystring2=mystring1.strip()
print (mystring1+"####")
Output
Innova Ediciones ####
print (mystring2+"####")
Output
Innova Ediciones####
```

I used the # at the end to show the space. `strip()` removes any spaces and newline characters on both sides of the string. If you want a specific character removed, you can pass it to the function (like `strip(" ")`).

Your second set returned the results you needed probably because your copy and paste removed the extra space at the end of those strings somehow.

When adding items to a set from an iterable, to avoid these extra spaces at the end, I usually do this.

```
myset=set()
for eachitem in myitems:
   myset.add(eachitem.strip())
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

when you use {} you are defined a dict. You can do this:

```
my_set = ['one', 'one', 'two']
len(my_set) #len == 3
real_set = set(my_set)
len(real_set) #len == 2
```

Comment: `isinstance({'one','two','three'}, set)` --> `True`. : `isinstance({'one','two','three'}, dict)` --> `False`.

Comment: [ ] creates a list
{} creates a dictionary... and a set

Comment: This isn't true. `{}` is used for both sets and dictionaries literals. It depends on if key/value pairs are provided, or just keys.